# Dynamic timezone configuration in python logger

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, logging

In the implementation I have:

```
config = yaml.load(f.read())
logging.config.dictConfig(config)
logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s')

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug("logger initialized...")
```

The application when starts, uses the timezone from TZ variable. However, when this timezone is changed later for some reason, it does not reflect in the python logger which is already running.

Is it possible to set the timezone dynamically in a already running process, which is using the python logger?

Comment: dynamically changing the timezone of a logging process? yikes that sounds like a nightmare. UTC and be done with it.

Comment: Its one of the corner case where TZ is set after the process is started and process picks up the default (UTC) timezone. Perhaps its a configuration issue. However, when a timezone is later configured, it should also be updated in the logging? What does python logger provides in this case?